# Accessing product from template

Tags: magento-1.7, product, template

I'm new to the whole Magento thing... 
I'm trying to show products on the front page. I registered a custom template and my home cms page uses it to load. In my template file, here is the code.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(41); 
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
foreach($_productCollection as $_product) {
```

No mather what I do or try, the `$_productCollection` contains an object and therefore, doesn't work with the `foreach`, giving me nothing in $_product. Where am I wrong?

Thank You!

Comment: you can do this through Magento admin area without doing it programmatically. I can go into more details if you would like me to.

Comment: I'd apreciate it, but is it automatic? the website is for a customer and I want him to only add a product to the category ID 41 and not having him to learn how to place them. And it must be at random.

Comment: what is the object instance of $_productCollection?

Comment: This is what I get when print_r : Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The problem was not in the code but in the catalog itself... I did not set inventory nor the website... I started that catalog with sample date with multiple storefront/websites.

After setting the product to in stock and clicking it to work in the main website, everything came together and the product appeared in the page.

Thanks to everyone who helped me on that one!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably your best option to show products on your homepage:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/how_to_create_a_featured_product

The other option is create a category called something like homepage products. Then load those products in the CMS page for your homepage using this type of code:

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="1" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Change the 1 in category_id="1" to whatever the category ID is (viewable on the catalog>manage categories page)

Comment: It seems all well and good, but I need custom markup for it all...

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: I'd argue it's not self-promotion bwhen it's from the official web site...